# Converting std::complex between array of two elements.

Tags: c++, arrays, types

`"WolframLibrary.h"` represents complex numbers using the struct:

```
typedef struct {double ri[2];} mcomplex;
#define mcreal(mc)  (((mc).ri)[0])
#define mcimag(mc)  (((mc).ri)[1])
```

which is just an array of two elements.  The standard library header `<complex>` defines it differently.  I want to make the compiler automatically convert between the two using the `=` operator, but I don't know how.  Suppose

```
mcomplex z1 = {3.2, 1.1};   //  <-- this is z1 = 3.2 + 1.1 I
std::complex<double> z2(-4.0, 0.5); // <-- this is z2 = -4.0 + 0.5 I
```

How do I tell the compiler that `z1 = z2` in my program means `mcreal(z1) = real(z2);  mcimag(z1) = imag(z2);`, and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to be able to use

```
z1 = z2;
```

is to provide a converting constructor from `std::complex<double>` to `mcomplex`.

Then, you can use:

```
std::complex<double> z2(-4.0, 0.5);
mcomplex z1 = z2;
```

or

```
mcomplex z1 = {3.2, 1.1}; 
std::complex<double> z2(-4.0, 0.5);
z1 = z2;
```

In order to be able to use the operations the other way, you need to provide a user defined conversion operator from `mcomplex` to `std::complex<double>`.

Finally, there is no need to use `typedef struct {...} mcomplex;`. Just use `struct mcomplex { ... };`

Here's program that builds successfully for me. Please note that `main` is empty on purpose. It just demonstrates the legal operations between `mcomplex` and `std::complex<double>`.

```
#include <complex>

struct mcomplex
{
   mcomplex(double re = 0, double im = 0)
   {
      ri[0] = re;
      ri[1] = im;
   }

   // Converting constructor.
   mcomplex(std::complex<double> const& c) : mcomplex(c.real(), c.imag()) {}

   // User defined conversion operator
   operator std::complex<double> () const
   {
      return {ri[0], ri[1]};
   }

   double ri[2];
};

void test1()
{
   std::complex<double> z2(-4.0, 0.5);
   mcomplex z1 = z2;
   (void)z1; // Shut up the compiler
}

void test2()
{
   mcomplex z1 = {3.2, 1.1}; 
   std::complex<double> z2(-4.0, 0.5);
   z1 = z2;
}

void test3()
{
   mcomplex z1 = {3.2, 1.1}; 
   std::complex<double> z2 = z1;
   (void)z2; // Shut up the compiler
}

void test4()
{
   mcomplex z1 = {3.2, 1.1}; 
   std::complex<double> z2(-4.0, 0.5);
   z2 = z1;
}

int main()
{
}
```

---

If you don't have the option of modifying the definition of `mcomplex`, your best option is to provide couple of non-member functions to do the conversions.

```
namespace MyApp
{
   mcomplex to_mcomplex(std::complex<double> const& c )
   {
      return mcomplex{c.real(), c.imag()};
   }

   std::complex<double> to_std_complex(mcomplex const& c)
   {
       return {c.re[0], c.re[1]};
   }
}
```

and then use

```
std::complex<double> z1(-4.0, 0.5);
mcomplex z2 = MyApp::to_mcomplex(z1);
```

and

```
mcomplex z1 = {3.2, 1.1}; 
std::complex<double> z2 = MyApp::to_std_complex(z1);
```

Comment: This is very nice!  It seems that I need to modify what's in `WolframLibrary.h`to make this work, which I prefer to avoid.  Is it possible to make this work after `"WolframLibrary.m"` is already loaded?

Comment: @QuantumDot, I am afraid not.

Comment: I just saw your edit, and it looks like a very reasonable way to go.  For performance reasons, is it possible to inline these functions?  I was thinking `inline mcomplex to_mcomplex(std::complex<double> const& c)` etc...

Comment: Actually, this doesn't compile.  Shouldn't the body of `to_mcomplex` simply be `return {real(c), imag(c)};`?  Also, `to_std_complex` doesn't seem to be returning the correct type since `std::complex<double>` is not an array of two elements.  Shouldn't it really return `std::complex<double>(mcreal(c), mcimag(c))`?

Comment: @QuantumDot, it works for me. Enabling C++11/C++14 might be what you need. See http://ideone.com/qQIjeJ.